# Put the loop variable into an attribute of a template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I've been trying to get this loop to work, but I keep getting the error

> card is undefined

How can I put the `img` property of the card object into the template?

```js
function Board() {
  this.cards = [new Card()];
}

function Card() {
  this.img = 'img.png';
}

Vue.component('card', {
  props: ['card'],
  template: '<img v-bind:src="card.img">'
});

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    board: new Board()
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <card v-for="card in board.cards" v-bind:key="card.img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't do Vue.js, but what jumped out at me was that you've said your `card` component takes a `card` property, but you're giving it a `key` property instead. The other thing that jumped out was trying to get `card.img` in two places (the template, and the markup).

If you change `v-bind:key="card.img"` to `v-bind:card="card"` (or `:card="card"`), in the markup, it works:

```js
function Board()
{
  this.cards = [new Card()];
}

function Card()
{
  this.img = 'img.png';
}

Vue.component('card',
{
  props:['card'],
  template: '<img v-bind:src="card.img">'
});

let app = new Vue(
  {
      el:'#app',
      data:
      {
       board: new Board()
      },
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <card v-for="card in board.cards" v-bind:card="card">
</div>
```

Or if you wanted `key` *as well* as `card` so Vue.js puts the cards in order by `card.img`, you'd have both:

```js
function Board()
{
  this.cards = [new Card()];
}

function Card()
{
  this.img = 'img.png';
}

Vue.component('card',
{
  props:['card'],
  template: '<img v-bind:src="card.img">'
});

let app = new Vue(
  {
      el:'#app',
      data:
      {
       board: new Board()
      },
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <card v-for="card in board.cards" v-bind:key="card.img" v-bind:card="card">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have only just started with Vue. All the notation is mind boggling!